# Why does desktop locking stop working after some time?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, awesome, xautolock

[`xautolock` is clearly running](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/ddbbc1dd8785e8a35edb0dc7351c75f706dae07d/.xprofile#L58):

```
$ ps wafux | grep [x]autolock
user   21410  0.0  0.0  20124  2628 ?        S    Nov05   0:04 xautolock -time 10 -notify 30 -notifier notify-send --urgency low --expire-time=10000 -- 'Locking screen in 30 seconds' -locker slock
```

However, when I try to [lock it](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/ddbbc1dd8785e8a35edb0dc7351c75f706dae07d/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L335-L341):

```
$ xautolock -locknow
Could not locate a running xautolock.
```

If I spin up another `xautolock` it works:

```
$ xautolock -time 10 -notify 30 -notifier "notify-send --urgency low --expire-time=10000 -- 'Locking screen in 30 seconds'" -locker slock&
[2] 18828
$ ps wafux | grep [x]autolock
user   21410  0.0  0.0  20124  2628 ?        S    Nov05   0:04 xautolock -time 10 -notify 30 -notifier notify-send --urgency low --expire-time=10000 -- 'Locking screen in 30 seconds' -locker slock
user   18828  0.0  0.0  20124  2708 pts/1    S    08:30   0:00      \_ xautolock -time 10 -notify 30 -notifier notify-send --urgency low --expire-time=10000 -- 'Locking screen in 30 seconds' -locker slock
$ xautolock -locknow # Runs fine and locks the desktop
```

What gives?

By now I've seen this on both my desktop and laptop. Please note that at least the first time after boot locking works fine. It's only after some unknown time or event that it starts failing.

---

I have *not* been able to reproduce this reliably. That is, I've tried the following approaches on my laptop and in both cases the [screensaver shortcut/command](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/33539b1e9e8ab78e69578903b531d577660ac964/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L336-L341) actually locks the desktop afterwards:

1. Close the lid
2. Wait for the computer to hibernate
3. Open the lid
4. Press the power button
5. Provide the login password followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

and

1. Lock the desktop
2. Same steps as above

---

Tracing the code:

1. [The line which prints the error message](https://github.com/l0b0/xautolock/blob/20e5cb3834f87056860f144f67dc55f1213d04a7/src/message.c#L285): `error1 ("Could not locate a running %s.\n", progName);`
2. That happens [if `messageToSend` is truthy](https://github.com/l0b0/xautolock/blob/20e5cb3834f87056860f144f67dc55f1213d04a7/src/message.c#L283) and [`type != XA_INTEGER`](https://github.com/l0b0/xautolock/blob/20e5cb3834f87056860f144f67dc55f1213d04a7/src/message.c#L250)
3. It looks like [`type` is set](https://github.com/l0b0/xautolock/blob/20e5cb3834f87056860f144f67dc55f1213d04a7/src/message.c#L245-L248) in the following statement:

   ```
   (void) XGetWindowProperty (d, root, semaphore, 0L, 2L, False,
                              AnyPropertyType, &type, &format,
                              &nofItems, &after,
                              (unsigned char**) &contents);
   ```

Does this mean that whether the running `xautolock` is detected can depend on the *window* that is focused? I'm also wondering if this call could be related to this [known bug](https://github.com/l0b0/xautolock/blob/20e5cb3834f87056860f144f67dc55f1213d04a7/Readme#L155-L158):

> 4. The -disable,  -enable,  -toggle,  -exit, -locknow, -unlocknow,
>      and  -restart  options  depend on  access to the X server to do 
>      their work.  This implies  that  they will be suspended in case 
>      some other application has grabbed the server all for itself.

---

Is it possible that `xautolock` conflicts with `xss-lock`, both of which are using `slock`? In addition to the `xautolock` line above I also have this [line in .xprofile](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/ddbbc1dd8785e8a35edb0dc7351c75f706dae07d/.xprofile#L60):

```
xss-lock slock &
```

---

Since both `xautolock` and `xss-lock` can call `slock`, I'm suspecting that the problem goes something like this:

- [`xautolock` runs `slock` after 10 minutes of inactivity.](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/ddbbc1dd8785e8a35edb0dc7351c75f706dae07d/.xprofile#L58)
- [`xss-lock` *also* tries to run `slock` after 10 minutes](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/ddbbc1dd8785e8a35edb0dc7351c75f706dae07d/.xprofile#L60):

  ```
  $ xset q | grep --after-context=2 --line-regexp --fixed-strings 'Screen Saver:'
  Screen Saver:
    prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
    timeout:  600    cycle:  600
  ```
- Only one `slock` client is actually spawned.
- `xss-lock` kills the wrong `slock`, which causes `xautolock` to crash or give up.

Since `xss-lock` can detect laptop sleep I'd like to use it instead of `xautolock`, but I can't seem to make `xss-lock` work with `notify-send`.

Comment: Which unix are you using?

Comment: I am running into this same issue. I haven't looked too deeply into it, but I would love to know an answer as well.

Comment: How are you starting it? I found the same thing recently when starting it from `.xinitrc`: I switched to a `--user` service file and it is no longer an issue...

Comment: Why you even try to run two separate screen lock timeout programs simultaneously?

Comment: @siblynx Because xautolock doesn't lock my laptop when I close it, and [I've not been able to get xss-lock to notify me that it's about to lock the screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243138/how-to-use-notify-send-with-xss-lock), so they complement each other. But as you can see via the link I'm working on the latter to avoid xautolock entirely.

Comment: You could avoid that by using proper tools for such a task, like proper acpid configuration which then called your `xautolock -locknow` and no problems with two same functionality programs.

Comment: @siblynx Do you have a link for such tools? The [Arch Linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid) doesn't mention screen saver setup.

Comment: Well I'd use busybox for that because I run small Linux based on musl+busybox. busybox includes acpid daemon which reacts when power button is pressed. I'm sure it can handle laptop specific actions too.

Comment: I don't understand what BusyBox has to do with an Arch Linux desktop installation. Can you please explain?

Comment: I am having this issue as well. It seems it doesn't have anything to do with xss-lock, as I am using xautolock exclusively, without DPMS or other locking.

Comment: Playing a video with mpv (but not mplayer) triggers the issue for me.  Both players have empty configurations.

Comment: A less-than-optimal workaround for this trigger is to add `stop-screensaver=no` to `~/.mpv/config`.  Of course, this means you have to manually disable locking when playing videos with mpv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, the xautolock process was still running in the background, but it wasn't listening to any `xautolock -locknow` commands. As mentioned by @jrm, **an application must be suppressing the "screensaver"**. For both of us, this was due to mpv (video player) disabling the screensaver.

For mpv, the fix is to add the following to `~/.config/mpv/config` or `~/.mpv/config`:

```
stop-screensaver=no
```

If you do not use mpv, it might be another application disabling the screensaver. Try some commonly used ones out to see which one it is.

---

If you want to **prevent automatic screen locking during video playback**, one common way is to use xautolock's "corners" feature:

```
xautolock -corners 000- -cornersize 30
```

With the above command, if you put your mouse cursor in the bottom right corner of the screen (within a 30px radius), auto-locking will be temporarily disabled.

---

One more thing to try is the `-resetsaver` option:

```
xautolock -resetsaver
```

Or the `-detectsleep` option:

```
xautolock -detectsleep
```

Comment: Good tips, thanks! I've been aware of my video player (VLC) disabling screen locking for many years, but honestly this issue is now so far back that I can't recall if my mind had simply blanked over this fact. Anyway I've stopped using `xautolock`, so the question is a bit moot now. Marking as accepted as the most useful answer so far. If anyone has the exact same issue I can delete this question to avoid a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use `xdg-screensaver lock` even when `xautolock -locknow` is not working.